# Programatically determine if in production in revel framework

Tags: go, revel

How can I programatically detect if I'm in production mode or development mode in revel framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are exported global variables in the [`revel`](http://revel.github.io/docs/godoc/revel.html) package:

```
var (
    RunMode string // Application-defined (by default, "dev" or "prod")
    DevMode bool   // if true, RunMode is a development mode.
)
```

So for example:

```
if revel.DevMode {
    // Running in development mode
} else {
    // Production mode
}
```

Comment: I actually found this on my own but still thanks! :D I have another question for you aswell.